# How to initialize record from session variable in rails so that we need not to execute query for initializing a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Is there any way to initialize a record from session. for e.g I have a organization object and I put this in session object like

```
session[:organization] = organization
```

Now I made a custom method `current_organization` *(I know about devise)* like

```
def current_organization
 Organization.new(session[:organization])
end
```

This will return organization object. My `organization` `belongs_to` a `team` a devise model and `team` `has_many :organizations` but when I call

```
current_team.organizations.includes?(current_organization)
```

in view. It is returning false even if it is included in team's organizations but doing this

```
current_team.organizations.reload.includes?(current_organization)
```

is returning true. I set the session variable with organization object before calling view where i am using above method. Is there any thing which I missed like I am not able to figure out the reason for not returning true even it is included?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the record first.

Until you save it into the database, it is likely not to show up when you query for the team's organization children.

```
session[:organization_id] = organization.id

def current_organization
    Organization.find session[:organization_id]
end
```

Comment: Actually record is already saved and I did fetched the organization record and tried to save in session variable. My question was on reloading why it returns true

Comment: in that case store only the organization_id and then call for that record. I'll update my answer

Comment: No my `current_organization` method is called before every action and I don't want to make a call for that record again and again

Comment: have you thought about writing a dynamic method into the team model called 'current_organization' that uses some db logic to pull what you consider to be the current_organization and avoiding a before_filter/before_action that sits in front of all of your actions? Let me try somthing

Comment: from what I can tell it is not possible to retrieve the actual Active Record Object without querying it. perhaps the best fit is to re-visit the design?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some googling i found that instead of using

```
Organization.new(session[:organization])
```

I should use

```
Organization.instantiate(session[:organization])
```

From [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/instantiate) I found that

> **instantiate(attributes, column_types = {}) public**
>
> Given an attributes hash, instantiate returns a new instance of the
>   appropriate class. Accepts only keys as strings.
>
> For example, Post.all may return Comments, Messages, and Emails by
>   storing the record’s subclass in a type attribute. By calling
>   instantiate instead of new, finder methods ensure they get new
>   instances of the appropriate class for each record.